# Rxandroidble-The method scanBleDevices(UUID... filters) is not support for two types service

Tags: android, rxandroidble

I got a problem that the method scanBleDevices(UUID... filters) cannot support to discover double kind of devices with different UUIDServices.

I guess that the relationship between the args are AND, but not OR. But How could I get the double kind of device with different UUIDService?

The code under there is that I want to discover the device with the uuid `00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB` and another device with uuid `6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E` , But i always cannot get the result with the code.
So, how can I solve the question?

```
scanScription = rxBleClient
            .scanBleDevices(UUID.fromString("00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"),  UUID.fromString("6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"))
            .subscribe(new Action1<RxBleScanResult>() {
        @Override
        public void call(RxBleScanResult rxBleScanResult) {
            if (!bleDeviceHashMap.containsKey(rxBleScanResult.getBleDevice().getMacAddress())) {
                bleDeviceHashMap.put(rxBleScanResult.getBleDevice().getMacAddress(), rxBleScanResult.getBleDevice());
                HashMap<String, String> ble = new HashMap<String, String>();
                ble.put("name", rxBleScanResult.getBleDevice().getName());
                ble.put("address", rxBleScanResult.getBleDevice().getMacAddress());
                bleDevices.add(ble);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform your own filtering:

```
final UUIDUtil uuidUtil = new UUIDUtil(); // an util class for parsing advertisement scan record byte[] into UUIDs (part of the RxAndroidBle library)
scanSubscription = rxBleClient
        .scanBleDevices()
        .filter(rxBleScanResult -> {
            final List<UUID> uuids = uuidUtil.extractUUIDs(rxBleScanResult.getScanRecord());
            return uuids.contains(firstUuid) || uuids.contains(secondUuid);
        })
        .subscribe(
            ...
        );
```

You can also split it into two flows right away:

```
    final UUIDUtil uuidUtil = new UUIDUtil();
    final Observable<RxBleScanResult> sharedScanResultObservable = rxBleClient
            .scanBleDevices()
            .share(); // sharing the scan between two subscriptions

    firstScanSubscription = sharedScanResultObservable
            .filter(rxBleScanResult -> uuidUtil
                    .extractUUIDs(rxBleScanResult.getScanRecord())
                    .contains(firstUuid)) // checking for the first UUID
            .subscribe(
                // reacting for the first type of devices        
            );

    secondScanSubscription = sharedScanResultObservable
            .filter(rxBleScanResult -> uuidUtil
                    .extractUUIDs(rxBleScanResult.getScanRecord())
                    .contains(secondUuid)) // checking for the second UUID
            .subscribe(
                // reacting for the second type of devices
            );
```

Comment: Wa~o. I got it ! Thanks for your help!!